# How can I extract the computed accuracies from a "train" object?

Tags: r

Consider the following sample data **test**:

```
z   a   b   c
0   1   40  185
0   1   25  128
0   0   32  100
0   0   29  100
1   1   30  107
0   0   30  133
1   1   38  132
1   1   37  127
1   0   30  184
1   0   40  199
1   1   26  185
0   1   21  185
0   0   21  134
0   0   20  137
1   1   22  135
0   0   23  189
1   0   32  109
1   0   31  152
1   0   38  130
1   1   37  191
0   1   39  168
1   0   28  183
0   1   26  171
1   1   23  164
0   1   32  111
0   0   34  131
1   0   30  121
1   0   27  195
1   1   29  117
1   0   26  187
1   0   34  183
0   0   28  189
0   1   34  150
0   1   34  176
0   1   24  140
1   0   37  181
0   1   36  109
1   0   39  198
0   0   32  164
```

I want to perform logistic regression with the outcome variable `z` and the predictor variables `a,b,c`.

Here is the code below:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(825)
fitControl <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10)
logitex <- train(z~ a+b+c, data=test, method="glm", trControl = fitControl)
logitex


set.seed(825)
fitControl2 <- trainControl(method= "cv", number=10)
logitex2 <- train(z~ a+b+c, data=test, method="glm", trControl = fitControl2)
logitex2
```

The output of the first block of code is:

Generalized Linear Model

```
39 samples
 3 predictors
 2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 35, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.521     0.042  0.239        0.48
```

The output of the second block of code is:

```
Generalized Linear Model 

39 samples
 3 predictors
 2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 35, 35, 35, 36, 35, 35, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.458     -0.1   0.189        0.394
```

Shouldn't the output of the first block of code have 10 rows (each row with accuracy, kappa, etc.)? Note that `z` is a factor.

Here is the structure of the data:

```
 'data.frame':   39 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ z: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ b: int  40 25 32 29 30 30 38 37 30 40 ...
 $ c: int  185 128 100 100 107 133 132 127 184 199 ...
```

Comment: What you are seeing is the printed output of the model, which includes the average accuracy, kappa etc across all folds and repetitions. The object does contain more information than that. Could you clarify whether you are looking for one row for each resampling, or one row for each fold?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: For the repeated cross validation, wouldn't you get average accuracy for each repeat? Whereas in just regular cross validation, you would just get one average accuracy? I am looking for one row for each resampling in the repeated cv.

Comment: Also, you might want to mention that the `z` variable in your data is a factor (or better yet, post the result of `dput(test)` instead of showing it as tab-delimited), since as of now reading the table in from a file will not reproduce your output (you get RMSE and RSquared instead of accuracy)

Comment: Re: your question: not necessarily. By default `print.train` prints the results of `logitex$results`, which averages across both repititions and folds (most users just want a single summary value, not many). You can see the results of all resamplings with `logitex$resample`, and confirm that `mean(logitex$resample$Accuracy)` is .521.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Is it better to do repeated cv or regular cv in general?

Comment: If you have the time to run it there's no reason not to do repeated CV. Any instance of performing CV is just one random sampling, and the estimates of accuracy etc have noise. Repeating the cross validation reduces that noise. This is especially true when your sample size is as low as this.

Comment: MrFlick's link is dead, perhaps we can get that old answer(s) and migrate them here